# Instantiating a class in python and error points at variable name

Tags: python, oop

I am following a youtube tutorial on creating a neural network. I came across this error while attempting to instantiate my class to check that everything was working

```
  File "neuralnet.py", line 24
  n = Neural_Network(X)
  ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My code is here,

```
class Neural_Network(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.inputLayerSize = 2
        self.outputLayerSize = 1
        self.hiddenLayerSize = 3
        self.W1 = np.random.randn(self.inputLayerSize, \
                                  self.hiddenLayerSize)
        self.W2 = np.random.randn(self.hiddenLayerSize, \
                                  self.outputLayerSize)

    def forward(self, X):
        # Propogation
        self.z2 = np.dot(X, self.W1)
        self.a2 = self.sigmoid(self.z2)
        self.z3 = np.dot(self.a2, self.W2)
        yHat = self.sigmoid(self.z3)
        return yHat

    def sigmoid(z):
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-z)

    n = Neural_Network()
    yHat = NN.forward(X)
    print(yHat)
```

It's probably something that I'm missing. I attempted to pass X into the instantiation of n and it still didn't work. I am using python 2.X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z)
```

Is missing a close parenthesis. Try this:

```
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
```

Often times, otherwise unexplainable "syntax error" messages are the result of errors in the *previous* line(s).

Comment: Perfect, solved my problem thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a ')' at the end of this line:

```
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z)
```